# How to get all documents in SharePoint Online for a user

Tags: office-365

Is there any way to get all documents for a user in SharePoint online enterprise, if not personal ?

I am looking for a JavaScript solution or maybe rest api. But I really want all single documents user has access to in portal of our company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely you should look into the `SharePoint Search API` for performing such a task.

For example, the following Search REST endpoint:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentClass="STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary" AND IsDocument="true" AND Author="John Doe"'
```

returns documents that have been created by John Doe.

### References

- [SharePoint Search REST API overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
- [SharePoint 2013 Search REST API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nadeemis/archive/2012/08/24/sharepoint-2013-search-rest-api.aspx) - a great article about
  SharePoint 2013 Search REST API query syntax

Comment: i had this in my mind but my manager is planning to get everyone in company office 365 personal where there is no search api. but thank you

Comment: @CustomizedName, you say in your question that you are using SharePoint Online Enterprise, and at the same time claims there is no search API. Getting me confused!

Comment: If you mean Office 365 Personal, there is really no connection to SharePoint at all I'm afraid